# C++ Get indentation level of line in qplaintextedit subclass?

Tags: c++, qt, text, indentation, qplaintextedit

I want to make a simple text editor for coding, but I have one problem, I want to indent the lines properly. I made it so that each time the return key is pressed, the program checks the character before the cursor, If it's a '{' or a ':' then it will enter a newline and add a tab character.
One small issue is that I want the program to get the number of tab characters in the line the cursor is in, and add them to the next line.

```
EXAMPLE:

class foo {
    void bar(){
        cout << "this is how the lines are supposed to look like" << endl;
    }
}

INSTEAD OF

class foo {
    void bar(){
    cout << "this is how it is now" << endl;
}
}
```

I tried making a while loop to catch until a new line is detected, but it kept giving me infinite loops. The problem with qplaintextedit is that it can't tell what line the cursor is in.
It has a character_at() function, but it returns an integer value, meaning that qplaintextedit has no x or y coordinates as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the current line is called a block in QPlainTextEdit.

```
    QChar lastChar = this->document()->characterAt(this->textCursor().position - 1);
    QString tabs = "";
    QTextCursor curs = this->textCursor();
    curs.select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
    
    static QRegularExpression rx("(?<=\u2029)(\\s+)");
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx.match(curs.selectedText());
    
    if (match.hasMatch()){
        tabs = match.captured(0);
    }
    this.insertPlainText("\n" + tabs);
    if ((lastChar == "{") or (lastChar == ":")){
        this->insertPlainText("\t\n" + tabs);
        this->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Up, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
        this->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Right, QtextCursor::MoveAnchor);
    }
    return;
```